# How can I make this color box for my item

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Here is how the result I want to achieve:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4fFy.png)

Here is my code base:

```
  let skillSetStr = useSkillset(userInfo.Skills);
  // In some cases the db returns the userInfo in different objects.
  // For now this fixes the problem.
  if (userInfo.Skills === undefined) {
    skillSetStr = skillStr;
  }

 return (
    <div className="container--inner_modal user-preview-modal">
        {skillSetStr ?
          <div className="user-preview-info">
            <div className="grid-item">Skillsets:</div>
            <div className="grid-item user-preview-info_data">{skillSetStr}</div>
          </div> : ""}
        {location ?
          <div className="user-preview-info">
            <div className="grid-item">Location:</div>
            <div className="grid-item user-preview-info_data">{location}</div>
          </div> : ""}
        {major ?
          <div className="user-preview-info">
            <div className="grid-item">Major:</div>
            <div className="grid-item user-preview-info_data">{major}</div>
          </div> : ""}
    </div>
```

Here is how my website look like right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K12Zg.png)

How can I achieve this in my react project?

Here is my scss file:

```
.user-preview-info {
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;


  .grid-item {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 18px 0;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .user-preview-info_data {
    color: rgba(0, 27,17,0.7);
    font-weight: 300;
  }

}

.user-preview_message-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #00B790;
  border-radius: 24px;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It's not about react, it's just css which you need to write. May I know how you are writing styles in your project?

Comment: @mdrahiem just update my post. Added scss file

Answer (score 0):

`Skillsets` section should include a component which accepts `skillSetStr` as props and returns a bunch of `<span>`s which you can style however you want.

Comment: Well you've already written a component, just need to write another one.
It would look like this:
`
<div className="grid-item">Skillsets:</div>
<Skillset skillList={skillSetStr} />
`

Comment: Did you create Skillset? I didn't have that component

Comment: Well yeah, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: I quite don't get your idea. Im so sorry

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some `padding` and a `background/background-color`.
*I have never used React before, so I don't have a solid solution that answers your question, but this is how you can do it in plain CSS*

For example:

```html
<style>
   .padding { padding: 5px 10px;}
   /* for the most part background & background-color does the same thing */
   .infoBg {background: #e7edff;} 
   .infoColor {color: #6380f1;}
   .fit {width: fit-content; height: fit-content;}
   .borderRound { border-radius: 5px;} 
</style>
<h3 class="padding infoColor infoBg fit borderRound">Hello</h3>
```